# Select popup in IE9 html debugger

Tags: debugging, internet-explorer-9

I want to view the html of an item in the IE debugger, that is only shown when clicking on a button.

The problem is that if I click or alt-tab over to the debugger the element closes and I can no longer select it.

Is there a shortcut or similar to Ctrl-B I can use from inside the IE window to select the element while it is open?